# Tree visualizer using IKVM in visual studio 2010 C# environment

Tags: weka, ikvm

I am using IKVM 0.46.0.2 to wrap a java application into a dll in visual studio 2010 C# environment.

And weka version is 3.7

I make a weka.dll using -sharedloader option

```
ikvmc -classloader:ikvm.runtime.ClassPathAssemblyClassLoader -target:library weka.jar LibSVM.jar
```

Finally, I was running sucessfully in C# console.

Console message is

```
Refreshing GOE props...
[KnowledgeFlow] Loading properties and plugins...
[KnowledgeFlow] Initializing KF...
```

It seems to be fine.

However, J48 tree does not appear.

There is no error and JFrame window is also well made.

Do you know what I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases this is a classloading problem. You have compiled 2 jar files in one dll. If there are identical files in both jar files (mostly in META_INF) then it will produce problems. In this case compile every jar file in a single dll.

If this not help then you can set a context classloader. Details are in the [wiki](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I still have a problem.
I tried to without libsvm.dll like ...
    ikvmc -classloader:ikvm.runtime.ClassPathAssemblyClassLoader -target:library weka.jar
It have the same problem with the previous work.
I guess that it is the IKVM problem but I don`t know what to do.

Comment: This does not compile in 2 dlls. Of course will does not solve the problem. You need to compile in one step into 2 dlls. Ask in the mailing list for more help.